# If malloc's can fail, how come stack variables initialization can't (at least we don't check that)?

Tags: memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

Would the OS send a warning to the user before a threshold and then the application would actually crash if there is not enough memory to allocate the stack (local) variables of the current function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... semantically speaking, there is no stack.

From the point of view of the language, automatic storage *just works* and dynamic storage *may fail* in well-determined ways (`malloc` returns `NULL`, `new` throws a `std::bad_alloc`).

Of course, implementations will *usually* bring up a stack to implement the automatic storage, and one that is limited in size at that. However this is *an implementation detail*, and need not be so.

For example, gcc [`-fsplit-stack`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code-Gen-Options) allows you to have a fractionned stack that grows as you need. This technic is quite recent for C or C++ AFAIK, but languages with continuations (and thousands or millions of them) like Haskell have this built-in and Go made a point about it too.

Still, at some point, the memory will get exhausted if you keep hammering at it. This is actually undefined behavior since the Standard does not attempt to deal with this, at all. In this case, typically, the OS will send a signal to the program which will shut off and the stack will *not* get unwound.

Comment: The OS can just free all the memory used by the running application, can't it?

Comment: "semantically speaking, there is no stack."   I think there is.  There has to be, it's where the return address is stored so when the function is finished, the Instruction Pointer can be properly set .

Comment: @SteveWellens: this is an implementation detail. The C++ Standard does not speak about instruction pointer and whatnot.

Comment: @Spidey: The OS can do many things, including releasing all resources owned by the application (memory, file handles, ...) and stopping its execution. Most OS have a mechanism to signal the application prior to doing this though, so as to let a chance to the application about doing something.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you would get a Stack Overflow run-time error.

Side note:  There is a popular web site named after this very error!

Comment: I ACTUALLY didn't notice that until now. REALLY REALLY. Not being ironic. I thought that stack overflow was related to buffer overflow.

Answer (score 4):

Stack allocation *can fail* and there's nothing you can do about it.

On a modern OS, a significant amount of memory will be *committed* for the stack to begin with (on Linux it seems to be 128k or so these days) and a (usually much larger, e.g. 8M on Linux, and usually configurable) range of virtual addresses will be reserved for stack growth. If you exceed the committed part, committing more memory could fail due to out-of-memory condition and your program will crash with `SIGSEGV`. If you exceed the reserved address range, your program will definitely fail, possibly catastrophically if it ends up overwriting other data just below the stack address range.

The solution is not to do insane things with the stack. Even the initial committed amount on Linux (128k) is more stack space than you should ever use. Don't use call recursion unless you have a logarithmic bound on the number of call levels, don't use gigantic automatic arrays or structures (including ones that might result from user-provided VLA dimensions), and you'll be just fine.

Note that there is no portable and no future-safe way to measure current stack usage and remaining availability, so you just have to be safe about it.

**Edit:** One guarantee you do have about stack allocations, at least on real-world systems, (without the split-stack hack) is that stack space you've already verified you have won't magically disappear. For instance if you successfully once call `c()` from `b()` from `a()` from `main()`, and they're not using any VLA's that could vary in size, a second repetition of this same call pattern in the same instance of your program won't fail. You can also find tools to perform static analysis on some programs (ones without fancy use of function pointers and/or recursion) that will determine the maximum amount of stack space ever consumed by your program, after which you could setup to verify at program start that you can successfully use that much space before proceeding.

Comment: Sorry, but Matthieu won the rep competition by 400 rep. LOL. Just kiddind, he won me on the "semantically speaking" part. Btw, good data you bought on the default/standard sizes of the heap on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The process would get killed by the OS if it runs out of stack space.

The exact mechanics are OS-specific. For example, running out of stack space on Linux triggers a [segfault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault).

Comment: You can easily check that by coding a recursive PHP function with no stop condition. You will have a Segmentation Fault from your PHP.

Comment: @Eregrith: How did PHP enter the picture? The question is tagged `[c]` and `[c++]`.

Comment: It doesn't even matter, because it has nothing to do with C and C++ and more relates to assembly.

Comment: @DeadMG: The language does matter. Stack overflow is typically handled *very* differently in higher-level languages (Python, PHP, even Java) than in lower-level ones (C, C++).

Comment: @aix It's an example. Have you ever been able to have a Segmentation Fault in PHP, without crushing your stack ? This way you'll be sure the stack IS corrupted and the Segfault does not come from elsewhere in some C code.

Answer (score 0):

While the operating system may not inform you that you're out of stack space, you can check this yourself with a bit on inline assembly:

```
unsigned long StackSpace()
{
    unsigned long retn = 0;
    unsigned long *rv = &retn;

    __asm
    {
        mov eax, FS:[0x08]
        sub eax, esp
        mov [rv], eax
    }

    return retn;
}
```

You can determine the value of FS:[*] by referring to the windows [Thread Information Block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_Information_Block)

Edit: Meant to subtract esp from eax, not ebx XD

Comment: I don't see a `windows` tag on the question or any mention in your answer that this is non-portable win32-specific code.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are making this function return to itself by overwriting the callee address on the stack? What will happen in the OS layer?

Comment: @Spidey All that code does is copy the address of the bottom of the stack into EAX, subtract the current value of ESP - which is the stack pointer - from EAX, and write the value of EAX to the 'retn' variable. How am i overwriting the return address?

Comment: @R Fair enough, but it does still have information related to his question. Also, it's not hard to deduce that this is windows related code, just look at the Wikipedia article i linked.

Comment: @Gogeta70 I misunderstood it, I though you were forcing some kind of recursion or something. I didn't get the mathematics though. Are you forcing esp to the max value? How? I thought you would increment it, not decrement it, to achieve this.

Comment: @Spidey, No, i'm not modifying the value of esp at all. I'm moving the address of the bottom of the stack into eax and then subtracting the value of esp from eax. Eax is then equal to the number of bytes available on the stack. Then, i write the value of eax to the 'rv' pointer and return the value of retn. For example, of the address of the bottom of the stack is 3000 and ESP is 1000, i subtract 1000 from 3000 and get 2000. So, you have 2000 bytes left on the stack.